# google maps change zoom with loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, loops, for-loop

I am using google maps api to generate map. 
Is it possible to make a javascript loop that will change maps zoom by 1 after 5 seconds till zoom reach 10?

The map is not a static map so I think only way to change the zoom is to refresh the page, but that will reset the loop.

```
var map = null;
     function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            center: {
              lat: 34.052234, 
              lng: -118.243685
            },
          zoom: 1,
          scale: 2,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          // mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
          };

          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the map zoom level from javascript using [`map.setZoom`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map):

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
  if (map.getZoom() == 10)
    clearInterval(timer);
}, 5000)
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gngcfrut/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = null;

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 34.052234,
      lng: -118.243685
    },
    zoom: 1,
    scale: 2,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    // mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
    if (map.getZoom() == 10)
      clearInterval(timer);
  }, 5000)
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```